# Xcode cannot run on simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

in Xcode, I can see the simulators (in Window->Devices), however XCode itself will not recognize the simulator as an option to run on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there may be two reason by which your Xcode not recognise simulator.

1.You have selected higher or lower version in development target.
[image]

2. Go to Xcode ---> window ---> Devices --> Add device on click + icon. it will be added a device on your Xcode .

Thanks

Enjoy coding.....